# Any way to change my final goal? (Spoilers)

Tags: no-mans-sky

So I got to Atlas again, and discovered that it would be destroyed.  After a lot of stuff, I got to decide what I wanted to do while the universe lasted.  I chose go to the center of the universe to find Atlas.  After reading what this does however, I dont really want to go to a new universe, I like this one fine.  I'd wrather "Explore the Galaxy" which is the whole point of the game anyway.  I'm kind of over the story now, it seems to have no end.  Anyway, my question is:  A.  Can I change my final goal?  and B. will having the wrong one change anything for my gameplay?  Thnx!

Comment: Not worth to post a new answer for this, but the new galaxy is no different from the old one strictly speaking. The only noteworthy difference is some parameters in the world generation algorithm that boost some planets types on other. Furthermore, you can get back to the Euclid galaxy whenever you want if you have a base there... so my suggestion would be to just complete the mission and then travel back. PS: one last thing - you will get some damaged system on your ship if you travel to the next galaxy, so if the techs are in cargo slots you will have to repair them.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it is also your multi-tool and suit tech that can be damaged when you travel through the center of the galaxy to another one, not just ship tech. No idea if this also affects your freighter or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No man's sky will remain an open sandbox. no matter what choices you choose throughout the story. You can select new missions, ignore them and build bases, ignore that and just fly the stars, whatever.

The only thing these choices alter is dialog and maybe a handful of events after the choice, but never any lasting or drastic changes. Your galaxy map will always have the navigations for Center of your current Galaxy, current mission(if any are active), a black hole, an Atlas Station, or just free explore. You can do whatever you want, whenever you want.

Comment: cool!  thnx for the answer, not really sure why they have such a long story, kind of distracts from the whole point of no mans sky,  although I like some of the lore.  To each his own though.  Thanks again!